# PMD and auto generated code in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, pmd

I'm using Netbeans to build a GUI application and PMD "complains" about things in the auto-generated code. Can I configure PMD to ignore auto-generated code (as I did with Checkstyle)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple things that you can do:

A. Alter the template for the type of form to include some of the magic strings that are discussed on this [page about suppressing PMD warnings](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/suppressing.html).

1. Use the Templates item of the Tools
   menu to open the 'Template Manager'
   dialog.
2. Find the folder labeled 'Swing GUI
   Forms' and expand that node.
3. Select a template and press the
   'Open in Editor' button.
4. Change the
   `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` to
   `@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked",
   "PMD"})`

Note: You can apply this last step to any of the forms that you have already created.

B. Create a ruleset that does not include the warnings that get violated by the generated code and use that ruleset instead. There is a [page that discusses creating rulesets](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/howtomakearuleset.html) and a page that [describes how to direct PMD to use an explicit ruleset when executed from the command line](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/running.html).